# project works only with appcompat 7:5

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have an android project which for some reason does not work without appcompat 7_5.

As a matter of fact, not even the hello world from the android developers hp works on my comuter without it.

I would like my projects to work with only appcompat 7.

As the code can obviously not be the reason (hello world), any one have any suggestions what it might be?

Thank you

Edit:

Ok, I changed the project.properties file which removed most of the mistakes, BUT now the gui is not working any more, as "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

My changes:

```
 target=android-19
#android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7_5
android.library.reference.2=../appcompat_v7
android.library=true
android.library.reference.3=../appcompat_v7_4
```

I only made the second line a comment everything else was there before. Now how to get R back?

I think this "R cannot be resolved...."thing was why I added appcpompat 7_5 in the first place.

Comment: Make sure you have your SDK updated

Comment: appcpmpat7 is in there if you mean that

Comment: I know it's in there. But it's updated?

Comment: your package name is `android.support.v7.appcompat`? That will cause trouble

Comment: why? the packagename is autogenerated. and yes, I updated just now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1: If you create a new app you can select the API level. Select Kitkat (the latest API level) while you create a new Android project. The latest version does't need the support (appcompat) libraries for older SDK versions.

Option 2: In the AndroidManifest.xml file you can change the min/max SDK targets. You should change:
android:minSdkVersion
android:targetSdkVersion

Then you can delete the support libraries.

I recommend option 1 because it's much quicker. Good luck;)

P.S. I dont think that you need to update.

Comment: I should use option 2 as my project is already finished....does it take that long to change one line? and what do you mean by I can delete the libs?

Comment: it doesn't take long to change one line :). In your classes you shoujld see in the top all the imports. There you should see a lot of support libaries which are being imported automatically. Example: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab; Try to remove all the support imports. You can get some error messages which need to be solver by importing the corresponding classes from the latest SDK.

Comment: I see wht you mean, only I do not get any import suggestions.

Comment: I think it's better to choose option one. Then you create the classes and you can copy yuour code.

Comment: Ok, I am just trying version one. But WHERE can one select and api level?

Comment: I only use eclipse. In eclipse you go to file>new project>new android project. There you can select Kitkat. If you use Android Studio you should search google

Comment: trying that. might take a while but if it works I vote for your answer

Comment: Nope. If I try to create any new project I get  DDMS files not found

Comment: I found that myself. I am using Linux and this approach does not seem to work there.

Comment: Im sorry but this should be a new question according to the stackoverflow guidelines. Your first question has already been answered right? Please click the checkmark. Thanks